# C++ simple timer/tick function

Tags: c++, timer, count

as the title says I want to create a simple timer/tick function that counts for example 5 minutes so that i can call an other function then the timer starts again an so on but without using sleep or a clock function. So is there any function or method so that it counts for example in seconds up or down? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's wrong with `sleep`? Is this something you're actually trying to do, or a coding puzzle?

Comment: "without using sleep or a clock function" : how would you measure 5 minutes without a clock ? `std::thread` + `std::chrono` should be good enough here.

Comment: I tried sleep but it completly pause the program and this is not good also tried something with counting down a int but I want something with "real time" as you know every System counts faster or slower and I also tried something with a clock function which is working well but I dont know im feeling it is not very "clear" coding it should be for windows

Comment: So you say clock functions are ok?

Comment: if used corrects, yes : show your timer code (with the clock) in your question to get an accurate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Although you said that you wanted to avoid "clock function", I don't see how to count 5 minutes without a clock. Here is a very basic, but **portable**, timer.

- [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) is used to create a thread
- [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) is used as a clock

**Result** : the `foo()` method is called every 5 minutes.

---

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello !\n";   
}

int main()
{
    std::thread([&]
    {
        while(true)
        {
            // Wait 5 minutes
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(5));
            // Call our method
            foo();
        }
    }).detach();

    // Execution continues ...
    std::cin.get();
}
```

---

**Notes :**

- I passed a lambda to the thread but any callable would do.
- [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) is full of cool stuff to manipulate date and times, you can easily tune your timer with it.